# MessagePoolMemoryStrategy initialization fails with sensor_msgs/msg/imu

Tags: ros, ros2, realtime, ros-crystal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My setup:

ROS2 crystal,   colcon build system,  Ubuntu 18.04.1,    gcc compiler:7.3.0

Hi ,
I tried initializing the  message pool memory strategy for two different message types, the "Twist" message from geometry_msgs and "Imu" msg from sensor_msgs. Here is the code:

```
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "sensor_msgs/msg/imu.hpp"
#include <rclcpp/strategies/message_pool_memory_strategy.hpp>   
#include "geometry_msgs/msg/twist.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);    
  auto memory_strategy_twist       =std::make_shared<rclcpp::strategies::message_pool_memory_strategy::MessagePoolMemoryStrategy  <geometry_msgs::msg::Twist, 1>>(); 

  auto memory_strategy_imu         = std::make_shared<rclcpp::strategies::message_pool_memory_strategy::MessagePoolMemoryStrategy <sensor_msgs::msg::Imu,1 >>();                                             
  
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

I get a compiler error:

```
/home/xxxx/demo1/src/test1-1.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/xxxx/demo1/src/test1-1.cpp:15:143: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be at
 least 2)                                                                                         
 :strategies::message_pool_memory_strategy::MessagePoolMemoryStrategy<sensor_msgs::msg::Imu    >>()
;                                                                                                 
                                                                                        ^~~
```

when I comment out  the  initialization for **memory_strategy_imu**  , the build is successful.
Any Ideas on how I can get it to compile for **Imu** message types?

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(demo1)

# Default to C99
if(NOT CMAKE_C_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
endif()

# Default to C++14
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)                                                                      
find_package(sensor_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(geometry_msgs REQUIRED)


add_executable(Demo_test
  src/test1-1.cpp                                                                                   )                                                                                               
 ament_target_dependencies(Demo_test
   "rclcpp"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "sensor_msgs"
   "geometry_msgs")
 
 install(TARGETS
   Demo_test
 DESTINATION bin)  
ament_package()
```

package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format2.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="2">
  <name>demo1</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>TODO: Package description</description>
  <maintainer email="xxx">xxx</maintainer>
  <license>TODO: License declaration</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>

  <build_depend>rclcpp</build_depend> 
  <build_depend>sensor_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>

  <exec_depend>geometry_msgs</exec_depend>  
  <exec_depend>rclcpp</exec_depend>  
  <exec_depend>sensor_msgs</exec_depend>  

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322950/messagepoolmemorystrategy-initialization-fails-with-sensor_msgs/msg/imu/) by [mann](https://answers.ros.org/users/38423/mann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2019-05-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not 100% sure, but I believe it looks like `sensor_msgs::msg::Imu` fails the `rosidl_generator_traits::has_fixed_size(..)` check (base version [here](https://github.com/ros2/rosidl/blob/afbdedca7ce3d2f92db1084cb56d7828311c9cf4/rosidl_generator_cpp/include/rosidl_generator_cpp/traits.hpp#L27-L28), specialised for `sensor_msgs::msg::Imu` in `include/std_msgs/msg/header__traits.hpp`), causing the `std::enable_if<..>` to fail ([here](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/ef41059a751702274667e2164182c062b47c453d/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/strategies/message_pool_memory_strategy.hpp#L41-L42)), causing your compilation to fail.

`sensor_msgs::msg::Imu` is not a fixed size message as it contains a `std_msgs::msg::Header`, which contains a `string`, which is (potentially) unbounded.

Checking `std_msgs/msg/header__traits.hpp` confirms this:

```
template<>
struct has_fixed_size<std_msgs::msg::Header>
  : std::integral_constant<bool, false> {};
```

I would actually expect all messages that have a `Header` to fail the check in a similar way.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0